# Route not being created to NATInstance using CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-ec2, nat, amazon-cloudformation

I have this Instance:

```
"NATInstance": {
  "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
  "Properties": {
    "ImageId": "ami-12345678",
    "InstanceType": "t2.micro",
    "NetworkInterfaces": [ {
      "AssociatePublicIpAddress": "true",
      "DeviceIndex": "0",
      "GroupSet": [{ "Ref" : "NATSecurityGroup" }],
      "SubnetId": { "Ref" : "PublicSubnet" }
    } ],
    "SourceDestCheck": "false",
    "Tags": [
      {
        "Key": "Name",
        "Value": "nat"
      }
    ]
  }
},
```

And I have this Route:

```
"PrivateSubnetToWorld": {
  "Type": "AWS::EC2::Route",
  "Properties": {
    "RouteTableId": { "Ref": "PrivateSubnetRoutes" },
    "DestinationCidrBlock": "0.0.0.0/0",
    "InstanceId": { "Ref" : "NATInstance" }
  }
},
```

When I create my stack though, literally everything else in the entire stack gets created except for this Route. I've also tried this with a NATGateway instead of using a NAT instance. In both cases the route doesn't get created. I always have to add the route in by hand. Otherwise everything in the entire stack gets created properly.

How can I work around this?

Comment: What do the CloudFormation events say about your route? Does it give any statuses for your route, like `CREATE_COMPLETE` or `CREATE_FAILED`?

Comment: Have you tried using "DependsOn" in your route referencing your instance, so that CloudFormation is clear that your route depends on the instance? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-dependson.html

Comment: I checked the events. There are no comments/warnings/notices, etc. It just says CREATE_COMPLETE. I have tried DependsOn. It doesn't change anything. Any other ideas?

Comment: Submit a ticket with AWS support.

Comment: In your question, you are stating that the route does not Created. In The comments your are stating that everything is created. Which one is it? Do the CloudFormation events state that the route ist created? Did you attach the route to the routing table?